# How To Ask for Job Relocation

Tags: job-change, relocation, internal-transfer

I currently work at a tech company based in San Francisco. More recently, I have had keen interest in relocating to Austin for numerous reasons such as proximity to family and significantly lower cost of living. Given that I have an exorbitant amount of student loans to pay off, moving to Austin would allow me to put more money on my loan note every month as my rent and expenses would nearly be halved. The company which I work at has a small office in Austin, TX as well. Would it be appropriate for me to ask for a job transfer? I would like to be frank with my employer -- do you think these are legitimate reasons to ask for a transfer? What would be the best way for me to request this? I would love to continue working on the same team - just remotely.

Comment: Is there anything about your job that you could imagine to yourself "My employer would not be comfortable with me doing this remotely"?

Comment: Be frank, and talk about work life balance, and be frank on how this benefits your personal life.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask.

However, working remotely -- even from another office -- can make advancing your career more difficult, since you are out of the informal networking loop. I've been doing it for a decade, and I know that there are opportunities I should have jumped on that I didn't find out about in time to investigate

And when moving to a lower-cost-of-living area, you may find getting a raise more difficult for a while, since it isn't uncommon to scale pay by costs. (Which I'd the f flip side of getting a cost-of-living raise when you relocate to a more expensive location.)

But the place to start is by asking your manager whether it's possible and what it would take.